# Error:setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ply-file-format

```
    if triangles is None:
        tridata = mesh['face'].data['vertex_indices']
        print(tridata)
        print(type(tridata))
        print(tridata.dtype)
        triangles = plyfile.make2d(tridata)
```

there have a error :setting an array element with a sequence.
I check the type of tridata:

```
[array([    0,  5196, 10100], dtype=int32)
 array([    0,  2850, 10103], dtype=int32)
 array([    0,  3112, 10102], dtype=int32) ...
 array([ 2849, 10076,  5728], dtype=int32)
 array([ 2849, 10099,  8465], dtype=int32)
 array([ 2849, 10098,  8602], dtype=int32)]

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

object
ValueError:Error:setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I don't know where is wrong?
There is the code of function "make2d" :

```
def make2d(array, cols=None, dtype=None):
    '''
    Make a 2D array from an array of arrays.  The `cols' and `dtype'
    arguments can be omitted if the array is not empty.

    '''
    if (cols is None or dtype is None) and not len(array):
        raise RuntimeError("cols and dtype must be specified for empty "
                           "array")

    if cols is None:
        cols = len(array[0])

    if dtype is None:
        dtype = array[0].dtype

    return _np.fromiter(array, [('_', dtype, (cols,))],
                        count=len(array))['_']
```

Comment: This is an array of object dtype containing arrays.  It isn't a 2d array.  It looks like the error is in the `make2d` method, but I don't know anything about it.  Maybe an error stack would help.  Or a reference to this `plyfile` source.

Comment: Thanks your comment .I added the information of  make2d()

Comment: I'd have to spend some time playing that use of `fromiter` to understand what it can  or cannot use.

Comment: I am also trying to understand this...

Answer (score 0):

Where's this code from?  The use of a compound `dtype` in `fromiter` is tricky.

```
In [102]: dt1=np.dtype([('_',int,(4,))])
In [103]: dt2=np.dtype('i,i,i,i')
In [104]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [105]: np.fromiter(x, dt1)
....
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
In [106]: np.fromiter(x, dt2)
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If I flatten the array, it works - except values are replicated:

```
In [107]: np.fromiter(x.ravel(), dt1)
Out[107]: 
array([([ 0,  0,  0,  0],), ([ 1,  1,  1,  1],), ([ 2,  2,  2,  2],),
       ([ 3,  3,  3,  3],), ([ 4,  4,  4,  4],), ([ 5,  5,  5,  5],),
       ([ 6,  6,  6,  6],), ([ 7,  7,  7,  7],), ([ 8,  8,  8,  8],),
       ([ 9,  9,  9,  9],), ([10, 10, 10, 10],), ([11, 11, 11, 11],)],
      dtype=[('_', '<i8', (4,))])
```

Converting the array to a nested list, works:

```
In [108]: np.fromiter(x.tolist(), dt1)
Out[108]: 
array([([ 0,  1,  2,  3],), ([ 4,  5,  6,  7],), ([ 8,  9, 10, 11],)],
      dtype=[('_', '<i8', (4,))])
In [109]: np.fromiter(x.tolist(), dt2)
....
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

But if I make it a list of tuples, I can create this structured array.  List of tuples is the normal way of filling a structured array.

```
In [110]: np.fromiter([tuple(i) for i in x.tolist()], dt2)
Out[110]: 
array([(0, 1,  2,  3), (4, 5,  6,  7), (8, 9, 10, 11)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

But with an object dtype array, none of these tricks work:

```
In [111]: a
Out[111]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([10, 11, 12, 13])],
      dtype=object)
```

I can make an array with `dt1` using assignment to an initialized array:

```
In [123]: b = np.zeros((3,), dt1)
In [124]: b
Out[124]: 
array([([0, 0, 0, 0],), ([0, 0, 0, 0],), ([0, 0, 0, 0],)],
      dtype=[('_', '<i8', (4,))])
In [125]: b['_']=x
In [126]: b
Out[126]: 
array([([ 0,  1,  2,  3],), ([ 4,  5,  6,  7],), ([ 8,  9, 10, 11],)],
      dtype=[('_', '<i8', (4,))])
```

I can also iteratively fill it from the array of arrays:

```
In [128]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     b['_'][i]=a[i]
     ...:     
In [129]: b
Out[129]: 
array([([ 0,  1,  2,  3],), ([ 5,  6,  7,  8],), ([10, 11, 12, 13],)],
      dtype=[('_', '<i8', (4,))])
```

Comment: Thanks your answer.I use the same code in the Python3.6.It can be run.

Comment: I have this exact same problem with an example project I am trying to run.  How did you end up fixing the make2d method so that it works properly?